# Is there a way to send proactive message to another member of Teams?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Can MS Teams chat-bot create a new conversation with other guy during the current activity?
With my chat-bot based on Microsoft Bot Framework I am trying to realize the scenario where an employee create a specific task with the help of my chat-bot and after the employee complete this activity my chat-bot immediately send a notification for the employee's manager.

As I know, to create proactive message I need to know manager's userId. For this purpose I got the code from the sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs

```
 var members = new List<TeamsChannelAccount>();
            string continuationToken = null;

            do
            {
                var currentPage = await TeamsInfo.GetPagedMembersAsync(turnContext, 100, continuationToken, cancellationToken);
                continuationToken = currentPage.ContinuationToken;
                members = members.Concat(currentPage.Members).ToList();
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);
```

and slightly changed it to look for a member who has manager's name and surname.

But the problem is that TeamsInfo.GetPagedMembersAsync always return only 1 member (this employee), not the whole team.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: we could not able to reproduce the issue on our side.Did you see any exceptions? How many members are there in the team? Could you please share more details?

Comment: the chatbot is installed for a channel, but user talks to bot 1:1. Is it correct?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the team details when you replied to bot in channel or are you trying you fetch details when bot is on 1:1 conversation? Could you explain your issue in more detail?